# Converter array json em retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Tenho o seguinte retorno em json

```
{
    "cardapio": [
        {
            "tipoprato": "SALADAS",
            "pratos": [
                {
                    "prato": "ALFACE + REPOLHO ROXO"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tipoprato": "PRATO PRINCIPAL",
            "pratos": [
                {
                    "prato": "ESTROGONOFE DE GR?O DE BICO"
                },
                {
                    "prato": "GALETTE DE PVT, GLUTEN E QUEIJO MUCARELA"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tipoprato": "ACOMPANHAMENTO",
            "pratos": [
                {
                    "prato": "FEIJ?O C/ MAXIXE, QUIABO E COUVE"
                },
                {
                    "prato": "ARROZ BRANCO"
                },
                {
                    "prato": "ARROZ INTEGRAL"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tipoprato": "CALDOS",
            "pratos": [
                {
                    "prato": "CALDO DE COUVE - FLOR"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

A principio seria duas classes: TipoPrato e Pratos.

A minha dúvida é como eu faria para trazer esse resultado para retrofit?

Sou novo no retrofit.

Seria preciso duas classes?

```
class Cardapio{
  private String tipo;
  private Prato[] prato; 
  ...
}
```

Classe prato

```
class Prato{
   private String prato;

}
```

Minha interface

```
GET("/restaurante/")
public void getCardapio(
   Callback<List<Cardapio>> cardapioList;
);
```

Ou seria melhor separar cada coisa, trazer só os Tipos de Pratos depois só os pratos?

O meu objetivo depois é fazer uma lista expansível

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Converter Array Json em Retrofit(2)

1 - Definir as classes ***modelo*** que serão usadas para mapear os dados do JSON:

**Cardapio.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Cardapio {

    @SerializedName("tipoprato")
    @Expose
    private String tipoprato;

    @SerializedName("pratos")
    @Expose
    private List<Prato> pratos = null;

    public String getTipoprato() {
        return tipoprato;
    }

    public void setTipoprato(String tipoprato) {
        this.tipoprato = tipoprato;
    }

    public List<Prato> getPratos() {
        return pratos;
    }

    public void setPratos(List<Prato> pratos) {
        this.pratos = pratos;
    }

}
```

**Prato.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Prato {

    @SerializedName("prato")
    @Expose
    private String prato;

    public String getPrato() {
        return prato;
    }

    public void setPrato(String prato) {
        this.prato = prato;
    }

}
```

**CardapioList.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CardapioList {

    @SerializedName("cardapio")
    @Expose
    private List<Cardapio> cardapio = null;

    public List<Cardapio> getCardapio() {
        return cardapio;
    }

    public void setCardapio(List<Cardapio> cardapio) {
        this.cardapio = cardapio;
    }

}
```

2 - Criar a ***Interface*** ondes serão definidas todas as possíveis operações HTTP:

**CardapioService.java**

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface CardapioService {

    @GET("/restaurante")
    Call<CardapioRequest> getCardapio();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem o *array* de `pratos` dentro do *array* de `cardapio` que está em um objeto. Basicamente isso resolve seu JSON:

```
/**
 * Cardapio seria o model para receber o conteúdo do cardapio
 */
public class Cardapio {

    @SerializedName("cardapio")
    private ArrayList<Conteudo> conteudo;

    /**
     * Este é um model que contem o conteúdo que do seu
     * cardapio que tipoprato e um array de pratos.
     */
    public class Conteudo {

        @SerializedName("tipoprato")
        private String tipoprato;

        @SerializedName("pratos")
        private ArrayList<Prato> pratos;
    }

    /**
     * Prato é um model que receberá o nome do prato
     */
    public class Prato {

        @SerializedName("prato")
        public String prato;
    }
}
```

Sua interface seria algo como:

```
@GET("/restaurante")
Call<Cardapio.Conteudo> getCardapio();
```

Comment: o modo de chamar a interface está certo lá minha pergunta?

Comment: @adventistaam desta forma ai não sei se funciona. Editei minha pergunta colocando como seria.

Comment: Não precisaria dos getters e setters não, não é?

Comment: Precisa, para quando você for atribuír os valores em algum outro momento. Achei que já estaria ciente disso. :-)

Comment: Entendi. Então segue o padrão né?

Comment: Só para resgatar o valor usando retrofit não precisa do get e set, mas você irá precisar deles em algum momento do seu código. Não coloquei porque vc perguntou apenas atribuições usando retrofit. Segue sim o padrão.

Comment: Blz. Valeu! É que estou começando no Retrofit.

Comment: @adventistaam você chegou a usar desta forma como passei?! Me dê um feedback em relação a essa resposta. Vi que você fez outra pergunta, mas primeiro queria que você validasse para que eu possa responder a outra pergunta, que seria baseado nessa ou não. =D

Comment: Na verdade estou tentando, como estou estudando, ainda não sei muitas coisas tipo: Estou usando sua sugestão mas não estou conseguindo visualizar no response porque seria uma lista e sublista. `public void onResponse(Call<List<Cardapio>> call, Response<List<Cardapio>> response) {
                List<Cardapio.Conteudo> cardapioResponse = response.body();
                //Percorre a lista e exbie o nome de cada respositório
                for( Conteudo cardapio : cardapioResponse ){
                    Log.i("Cardapio", cardapio.getConteudo().toString() );
                }
         }`

Comment: Olha esse artigo do Vogella. Acho que vai te ajudar bastante: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: Blz. Estou dando uma estudada nele também. Valeu